# hola tengo el siguiente código, comparar un caracteres por teclado con otro

Tags: java

necesito comparar un caracteres por teclado con una seri de otros caracteres, si no iguales sale un mensaje

**he intentado con un String y arrys**

```
String c = "'A','E','I','O','U'";
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("...");
        String L = s.nextLine();
        
        if (L.equals("A")) {
            System.out.println("...");
        } else if (L.equals("a")){
            System.out.println("...");
        }
        else if (L.equals("Z")){
            System.out.println("...");
        }
        else if (L.equals("z")){
            System.out.println("...");
        }
**el problema es este no encuentro la manera de que funcione**
>       else if (L.contains("'A','E','I','O','U'")) {
>       System.out.println("...");

        } 
        else if (L.equals("'a','e','i','o','u'")){
            System.out.println("...");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("...");
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
    char[] vocalesMin = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    char[] vocalesMay = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("por favor, introduzca una letra: ");
    char letra = teclado.next().charAt(0);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < vocalesMin.length; i++){
        if (letra == vocalesMin[i]){
            System.out.println("La vocal " + vocalesMin[i] + " coincide con " + letra);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vocalesMay.length; i++){
        if (letra == vocalesMay[i]){
            System.out.println("La vocal " + vocalesMay[i] + " coincide con " + letra);
        }
    }
```

Puedes hacerlo un poco más funcional y elegante si utilizas una clase:

```
class ComprobarLetras {
    //creamos los array de caracteres a comparar, podríamos agregar otros para vocales acentuadas
    char[] vocalesMin = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    char[] vocalesMinA = {'á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú'};
    char[] vocalesMay = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    char[] vocalesMayA = {'Á', 'É', 'Í', 'Ó', 'Ú'};

    public boolean metodoComprobarMinusculas(char letra){
        boolean res = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < vocalesMin.length; i++){
            if (letra == vocalesMin[i]){
                res = true;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    public boolean metodoComprobarMinusculasA(char letra){
        boolean res = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < vocalesMinA.length; i++){
            if (letra == vocalesMinA[i]){
                res = true;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    public boolean metodoComprobarMayusculas(char letra){
        boolean res = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < vocalesMay.length; i++){
            if (letra == vocalesMay[i]){
                res = true;
            }
        } 
        return res;
    }
    public boolean metodoComprobarMayusculasA(char letra){
        boolean res = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < vocalesMayA.length; i++){
            if (letra == vocalesMayA[i]){
                res = true;
            }
        } 
        return res;
    }
}
```

Para llamarla, desde el método main:

```
private static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("por favor, introduzca una letra: ");
    char letra = teclado.next().charAt(0);
    
    ComprobarLetras misMetodos = new ComprobarLetras();
    boolean respuestaMin = misMetodos.metodoComprobarMinusculas(letra);
    boolean respuestaMinA = misMetodos.metodoComprobarMinusculasA(letra);
    boolean respuestaMay = misMetodos.metodoComprobarMayusculas(letra);
    boolean respuestaMayA = misMetodos.metodoComprobarMayusculasA(letra);
    
    if (respuestaMin == true){
        System.out.println("La vocal '" + letra + "', es minúscula");
    }
        else if (respuestaMinA == true){
            System.out.println("La vocal '" + letra + "', es minúscula acentuada");
        } 
            else if (respuestaMay == true){
                System.out.println("La vocal '" + letra + "', es mayúscula");
            }
                else if (respuestaMayA == true){
                    System.out.println("La vocal '" + letra + "', es mayúscula acentuada");
                }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para comenzar debes plantear bien tu pregunta, tu consulta es sobre como comparar una letra ingresado por teclado con un arreglo definido, pero en el código que compartes haces uso del método contains() el cual se usa para verificar que una subcadena se encuentra dentro de otra cadena.
Entonces si tu consulta trata sobre comparar una letra, puedes usar el código  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/457269/193364
Si deseas también comparto otra solución.

```
public class Caracteres {    
    
    private void comparar(){ 
        ArrayList<Character>  minusculas=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Character>  mayusculas=new ArrayList<>();
        minusculas.add('a');
        minusculas.add('e');
        minusculas.add('i');
        minusculas.add('o');
        minusculas.add('u');
        
        mayusculas.add('A');
        mayusculas.add('E');
        mayusculas.add('I');
        mayusculas.add('O');
        mayusculas.add('U');
        
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("por favor, introduzca una letra: ");
        char letra = teclado.next().charAt(0);        

        for(Character c:minusculas){
            if(c.equals(letra)){
                System.out.println("La letra ingresado es una vocal minuscula");
            }
            else System.out.println("La letra ingresado no es una vocal minuscula");
        }
        
        for(Character c:mayusculas){
            if(c.equals(letra)){
                System.out.println("La letra ingresado es una vocal mayúscula");
            } 
            else System.out.println("La letra ingresado no es una vocal mayúscula");
        } 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Caracteres c= new Caracteres();
        c.comparar(); 
    } 
}
```